# is this even possible with `jq`?

Tags: json, jq

I have some JSON data that looks like this

```
[ 
   {Key: "fruits/red/apple", Value: "Red apples"}, 
   {Key:"fruits/green/lime", Value: "Green Limes"}, 
   {Key: "fruits/blue/berries/blueberry", Value: "Blue Berries"}, 
   {Key: "vegetables/red/tomato", Value: "Red Tomatoes"}, 
   {Key: "vegetables/green/cucumber", Value: "Green Cucumbers"} 
]
```

And I am trying to extract the data to a nested JSON-tree structure like

```
{
  "fruits": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "fruits",
    "children": [
       { 
          "id": 2, 
          "name": "red", 
          "path": 1.2, 
          "children": [ { "id": 3, "name": "apple", "path": 1.2.3 } ]
       },
       { 
          "id: 4, 
          "name": "green",
          "path": 1.4, 
          "children": [ {"id": 5, "name": "lime", "path": 1.4.5} ]
       },
       { 
          "id: 6, 
          "name": "blue", 
          "path": 1.6, 
          "children": [ {"id": 7, "name": "berries", "path": 1.6.7, "children": [{...}] } ] 
       } 
    ]
  },
  "vegetables": {...}
}
```

I am new to jq and have something like this that gives me one level of data, but am lost on how to do running counters and recursion

```
[ .[] |  { name: .Key, description: .Value, children: ( [.Key | split("/")] | .[0] | to_entries ) } ]
```

appreciate any pointers on this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The desired output is not JSON, and it would be difficult to produce those non-numeric paths (e.g. 1.2.3). You could obviously add quotation marks to make them strings, but it would be much better to choose a more standard or convenient path representation.

Other than that, you can rest assured that jq is up to the task, though it would require some expertise in programming generally, or at least fluency with jq.